# Postgresql DB performance varies across schema issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a postgresql db with 2 different schema. but noticed that there are different in term of the query performance even though it is exactly the same query, same table sitting in both schema, same indexes created for both. for e.g schema A would return the result faster than schema B.

would like to seek any guidance/direction on what to check and to be done.

Comment: you need to provide your queries and their execuation plans

Answer (score 0):

Check the explain plans against both.

Check the stats (e.g. pg_stat_user_tables).

Check the size of the respective tables

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('whatever')
```

Try those and if the difference isn't obvious, rephrase the question with more details.